# When I try to load my create.html.erb page, I get this error "param is missing or the value is empty"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I got this error on loading the page and I would guess that it has somethinng to do with my create method in the controller
My controller looks like this

```
class StoryController < ApplicationController
def index
  @story = Story.all
end

def new
  @story = Story.new
end

def create
  @story = Story.new(story_params)
  if @story.save
      flash[:notice] = "Story created successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
  else
      flash[:notice] = "Story is invalid, man"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
end

end

def show
   @story = Story.find(params[:id])
end
private
def story_params
 params.require(:story).permit(:story_title, :story_body)
end

end
```

My create.html.erb looks like

```
        <%= form_for @story ,url: story_path do |f| %>
        <%= label :story, :title %><br />
        <%= text_field :story, :story_title %>

        <%= label :story, :body %><br />
        <%= text_field :story, :story_body %>
        <%= submit_tag 'Create story' %>
        <% end %>
```

My create.html.erb didnt look like this before, I changed it to that after I read some questions about how form_for would work instead of form_tag for the story_params.
But either way, I still get the error anyways and I would like to know why and if there is a fix for it.

Comment: You have `create.html.erb`? seriously?

Comment: What are your params for create? (Look in the console window where your server is running.)

Comment: i am still very new to rails, Am I not supposed to have a create.html.erb

Comment: It should almost certainly be `new.html.erb`

Comment: It just says parameter missing or the value is empty: story on the console log

Comment: does it matter which one I use? either new or create?? as long as my controller code is correct. I have a new.html.erb but I could just copy the code in there and still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create method is a POST... so when he enters story/create he's already expecting those values... that's why he says he can't find the params... i didn't look at the code deeply but it seems fine. Just change the name of the view to new.html.erb. New is the setup for create.

In new you setup the values and then invoke create where the controller actually creates the story.

Just change the name of the view to **new.html.erb** and change it to this

```
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
<%= f.label :title %><br />
<%= f.text_field :story_title %>
<%= f.label :body %><br />
<%= f.text_field :story_body %>
<%= submit_tag 'Create story' %>
<% end %>
```

as the other user said. you need to say that those inputs belong to form |f| the text_field belongs to f, **f.text_field**

And of course you access that view through stories/new

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not thinking it was expecting those parameters on entering story/create. So i would just rename that to new.html.erb.

Comment: create is always a POST method... it doesnt use a view :) glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

very first, you don't need to specify a path if you are using form_for and if you don't want to submit a form on the custom route.

If you are using new object then it will submit form on create method and for existing object it will submit form on update method.

So your form will be,

```
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :story_title %>
  <%= f.label :body %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :story_body %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Create story' %>
<% end %>
```

And this form needs to be in new.html.erb file.

This form will submit your form to create action with post method and from there you need to do render or redirection depending upon condition. So your controller will be,

```
class StoryController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @story = Story.all
  end

  def new
    @story = Story.new
  end

  def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    if @story.save
        flash[:notice] = "Story created successfully"
        flash[:color]= "valid"
        redirect_to story_path(@story)
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Story is invalid, man"
        flash[:color]= "invalid"
        render :new
    end
  end

  def show
     @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
    def story_params
     params.require(:story).permit(:story_title, :story_body)
    end
end
```

If you do `rake routes` in the termial, you can see all methods with its expected methods

Also according to rails conventions, if you have story model then you can directly create :title & :body attributes instead of :story_title and :story_body

Comment: Thanks! this worked, but I didn't understand why until I saw the accepted answer's point of view. You were of great help

Comment: you are welcome. .. at least you understood what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this make changes in the create.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for @story ,url: story_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :story_title %>

    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :story_body %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Create story' %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I still get the same error

Comment: param is missing or the value is empty: story

Comment: can you send me param?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your attributes for the `Story` object are named `story_title` and `story_body` ?

If not, your `story_params` should be like this :

```
def story_params
 params.require(:story).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

And also, apply @koshlendra suggestion, he's right.

I suggest you to generate a scaffolding for a fake resource to see how it's supposed to work :

```
rails g scaffold Fake title:string body:text
```

Then look at the generated controller and views to understand fully how it works.

Comment: My attributes are story_title and story_body, thats for sure. I generated them myself. Generating a fake scaffold would help me understand better, thank you!